# Oracle double conversion

Tags: sql, vb.net, oracle, types, plsql

I have this example:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
   VALUE   NUMBER (5, 2)
);

INSERT INTO test
     VALUES (6.3);

SELECT * FROM test;
```

In table test, I have a value of 6.3.
I have an application in .NET who queries this table and returns a single value of `6.3`.
Assuming the value is stored in the s variable like this:

```
Dim s As Single = 6.3
Dim d As Double = CDbl(s)
```

.NET converts the single into a double, and the variable d has this value: 6.3000001907348633. I understand that is a different representation of the 6.3 value, but when I'm using this `d` value in a operation like this:

```
(795407.2 * d) / 100 = 50110,6551171188
```

in PL\SQL when I'm querying the table, I want to get the `6.3000001907348633` value instead of `6.3`.
How can I convert this, or there is a datatype that does that? I've tried the `BINARY_FLOAT` and `DOUBLE PRECISION` types, but they don't convert this.

EDIT: Using `6.3` value I get: `(795407.2 * d) / 100 = 50110,6536`. if I round the value to get two decimal places (and assuming that this is a monetary value, I get `50110,66€` and `50110,65€` respectively).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `BINARY_FLOAT` Data Type in your SQL.

It represents a 32-bit floating point number in Oracle:

```
SQL> select cast(6.3 as BINARY_FLOAT) num,
  2         to_char(cast(6.3 as BINARY_FLOAT),'0.00000000') num_to_char
  3  from dual;

       NUM NUM_TO_CHAR
---------- -----------
  6,3E+000  6.30000019
```

**Edit:**

*Sorry, I was too fast and didn't read all your trials*

For compatibility purposes, try convert your number / literal to `BINARY_FLOAT` and then to `BINARY_DOUBLE`:

```
SQL> select TO_CHAR(cast(cast(6.3 as BINARY_FLOAT) as BINARY_DOUBLE),'0.000000000000000000') MyNum from dual;

MYNUM
---------------------
 6.300000190734863300
```